# Node mongoose typescript how to type { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm use mongoose with typescript
following this https://medium.com/@agentwhs/complete-guide-for-typescript-for-mongoose-for-node-js-8cc0a7e470c1

I don't know how to type

> following: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],

Can you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, what you define in mongoose schema only for mongoose to understand and type script doesn't care about it. If you populate `following` when retrieve record your interface will be `following: User[]`, if not it will be an array of string `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

When using defined types for mongoose and typescript you have to create an interface or type eg

```
import {Document} from "mongoose"

type UserType={
 username:String,
 _doc:any
 }&Document
```

//Or

```
interface IUser extends Document{
 username:String,
 _doc:any
 }
```

The `_doc` is used to get the body of the object body on query restructuring
Say you have a Blog and has user who is the author how do we map that?

```
type BlogType={
    title:{
    type:String,
    required:true
 },
author:{
   type:ShemaTypes.ObjectId,
   ref:'User',
   required:true,
},
 comments:{
    type:[
{
    user:ShemaTypes.ObjectId,
    content:String,
}
  ]
}&Document
```

Using the ref makes it easy to query the other table as a join for the table in which the Object Id is referenced
When working with arrays you just define the structure of data you want to store in the type property